# How do I set the sender name?

Tags: 7, emails

When emails are sent from my dev drupal site to new users the sender is listed as the first part of the site's email address ("info" from "info@mydomainname.com.au" (screenshot below)). Ideally I would like it to be the site's name. How can I control this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: In my case i normally use the [SMTP module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`drupal_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) supports a display name in the From: field, but it's up to the whatever module you're using to send mail. If you'd like to force the name, you can use the [MIMEMail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module.

Once installed, under the **Configuration > System > Mimemail** administration menu, you can set the default Name/Email that will be sent.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Shawn. I really appreciate your kindness.